# Applying Perron's formula to derivatives of the Riemann zeta function: my proof is wrong but I can't figure out why.

Tags: analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Edit (before anyone fights through it): found the mistake.

Let $k\in \mathbb N$ and $x\in \mathbb R$.  I can't figure out what is wrong with the following proof that
\[ \sum _{n\leq x}(\log n)^k\log (x/n)\ll _kx(\log x)^{k/2+1}\]
which is obviously nonsense since the LHS is
\[ \approx x(\log x)^{k}.\]
By one of the Perron formulas, the sum in question is
\[ =\frac {(-1)^k}{2\pi i}\int _{(c)}\zeta ^{(k)}(s)\frac {x^sds}{s^2}\]
for any $c>1$.  If for some $c>1$ we could show the bound
\[ \zeta ^{(k)}(s)\ll \log x\hspace {10mm}(1)\]
for $\sigma =c$ and $t\ll 1$ then the part of the integral with $t\ll 1$ would be
\[ \ll x^c\int _{\sigma =c\atop {|t|\ll 1}}\frac {|\zeta ^{(k)}(s)|ds}{|s|^2}\ll x^c\log x.\]
Since for large $t$ we have $\zeta ^{(k)}(s)\ll (\log t)^{k+1}$ (I think? In any case, a $\log t$ power?), the part of the integral with $t\gg 1$ is trivially $\ll x^c$.  So the whole integral is $\ll x^c\log x$ and on choosing
\[ c=1+\frac {k\log \log x}{2\log x}\]
we then get the claim, so our task is to establish $(1)$ for $\sigma =c$ and $|t|\ll 1$.  So let's suppose $s$ satisfies these conditions and prove $(1)$.

Since
\[ \left (\frac {d}{dU}\right )\left [\frac {(\log U)^k}{U^s}\right ]=\frac {k(\log U)^{k-1}}{U^{s+1}}-s\frac {(\log U)^k}{U^{s+1}}\ll \frac {(\log U)^k}{U^{\sigma +1}}\]
we have with partial summation, for any $Y>X>0$,
\[ \sum _{X<n\leq Y}\frac {(\log n)^k}{n^s}=\frac {(\log Y)^k}{Y^s}\sum _{X<n\leq Y}1-\int _X^Y\left (\frac {d}{dU}\right )\left [ \frac {(\log U)^k}{U^s}\right ]\left (\sum _{X<n\leq U}1\right )dU\]
\[ \ll \frac {(\log Y)^k}{Y^{\sigma -1}}+\int _X^Y\frac {(\log U)^kdU}{U^{\sigma }}\]
so that letting $Y\rightarrow \infty $ we have
\[ \sum _{n>X}\frac {(\log n)^k}{n^s}\ll \int _X^\infty \frac {(\log U)^kdU}{U^{\sigma }}\]
and the integral here is I believe
\[ \sum _{r=0}^{k-1}\frac {(-1)^rk!}{(k-r)!(1-\sigma )^{r+1}}\left (\frac {(\log U)^{k-r}}{U^{\sigma -1}}\right )_X^\infty +\frac {(-1)^kk!}{(1-\sigma )^k}\int _X^\infty \frac {dU}{U^\sigma }.\]
Take $X>x$.  Since in particular $\sigma \geq 1+1/\log x\geq 1+1/\log X$, all the terms are
\[ \ll \frac {(\log X)^{k+1}}{X^{\sigma -1}}\]
so we've shown
\[ \sum _{n>X}\frac {(\log n)^k}{n^s}\ll \frac {(\log X)^{k+1}}{X^{\sigma -1}}.\]
On the other hand for $U$ large $(\log U)^k/U^{\sigma -1}$ is a decreasing function of $U$ (we worked out the derivative above) so
\[ \sum _{n\leq X}\frac {(\log n)^k}{n^s}\ll (\log X)\max _{N\leq X}\left [ \sum _{N<n\leq 2N}\frac {(\log n)^k}{n^\sigma }\right ]\ll (\log X)\max _{N\leq X}\left [ \frac {(\log N)^k}{N^{\sigma -1}}\sum _{N<n\leq 2N}\frac {1}{n}\right ] \ll \log X\]
so actually
\[ \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {(\log n)^k}{n^s}\ll \log X\left (1+\frac {(\log X)^{k}}{X^{\sigma -1}}\right ).\]
The LHS is $(-1)^k\zeta ^{(k)}(s)$ and the RHS is, on setting $X=x^2$,
\[ \ll \log x\left (1+\frac {(\log x)^{k}}{x^{2(c-1)}}\right )=2\log x\]
and we've shown $(1)$.

Comment: I'm just curious why you want to use Perron formula instead of directly evaluating the sum via Euler-Maclaurin formula

Comment: I would check dependencies in all computations as you use a $c$ that depends on $x$ so in particular all the derivatives of $\zeta$ on the line $c$ may have estimates that depend both on $x$ and on $t$

Comment: TravorLZH it's something i don't understand in a more difficult argument, but what i don't understand is the same as in this case.

Conrad thanks for looking at it.  i realised that my mistake is in the line "for large $U$, that function is increasing".  that's false.